# Dynamic field list for MultiMatch - Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have a requirement to have a search for a document type with a variable/dynamic number of fields being queried against. For one search/type it might be Name and Status. For another, the Description field. The fields to be searched against will be chosen by the user at run time.

To do this statically appears easy. Something like this to search in Name and Description fields. (Assume that rootQuery is a valid searchDescriptor ready for the query.

```
rootQuery.Query(q => q.MultiMatch(mm => mm.Query(filter.Value.ToString()).Fields(f => f.Field(ff => ff.Name).Field(ff => ff.Description))));
```

However, we don't want to have a library of static queries to handle the potential permutations if possible. We'd rather do something dynamic like:

```
foreach (var field in string-list-of-fields-from-user)
{
  rootQuery.Query(q => q.MultiMatch(mm => mm.Query(filter.Value.ToString()).Fields(f => f.Field(ff => field);
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `string` list of fields directly to `.Fields(...)`

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
            .Query("query")
            .Fields(new string[] { "field1", "field2", "field3" })
        )
    )
);
```

which yields

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "fields": ["field1", "field2", "field3"],
      "query": "query"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something minor but intellisense just wasn't especially helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `string` implicitly convert to `Field`, and `Fields` has implicit conversions from `string[]` (plus others). Sadly, intellisense isn't too helpful with implicit operators, so this should be documented better